# How to label regions that they do not have same values?

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, scikit-image

I have stacked 5 probability map in a numpy array (`a` with the shape 256x256x5), that I have stacked them and then I get the `argmax` of all of them that final output is show by different 5 colors, however, the values correspond to a pixel within an area are not same (values are changing between [0,1]).

```
max_= np.argmax(a, axis=2)
plt.imshow(max_)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I do not know how to separate each object by value, because pixels inside a region do not have same values. Does someone know how to label this five objects (colored parts and including background)?

Comment: Hi, your question is not very well formulated. What do you mean by "the values correspond to a pixel within an area are not same (values are changing between [0,1])" ?

Comment: @Ben thanks for your comment, sorry for poor English, what I mean is, although each object is shown with different colors after getting argmax from 5 arrays, the values by moving the cursor within each region are not same. How to label the areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want the maximum probabilities themselves, not the *indices* of the maximum probabilities. (Small point: if you array really is shape 5 × 256 × 256, then I think you did `np.argmanx(a, axis=0)` to get that result.)

This will give you the maximum probabilities themselves:

```
max_prob = np.amax(a, axis=0)
```

If you want each 'object' on its own, you could then do this for each of the regions:

```
prob_1 = np.zeros((256, 256))
prob_1[max_ == 1] = max_prob[max_ == 1]
prob_1[prob_1 == 0] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I want, Could I ask how to bring all of them together in one array with their labels?

Comment: If you do something like `probs = np.stack([prob_0, prob_1, prob_2])` then you'll have a single array with the 'label' as the index of the first dimension, so `probs[0]` is the array of probabilities for the first label. Or you could equally well store them in a list or dict, depending on what you want to do with them.

Comment: Thank you very much once again. It was a big help